# Java - overridden method not getting called

Tags: java, class, derived

I'm working on a Java exercise and can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I made a Movie class (with variables: rating, title, movieId and a constant for FEE_AMT) and then extended the class with: Action, Comedy and Drama. These derived classes have no other variables, just a different FEE_AMT.

In Movie (and derived classes) there is a method to calculate the late fees due:

```
/**
* Returns the late fee due on a Movie rental
*   @param  days the number of days for late fee calculations
*   @return   true or false depending on the evaluation of the expression
**/ 
public double calcLateFees(int days){
    return(days * FEE_AMT);
}
```

If I just call the method outright with the object, for ex: `comedy1.calcLateFees(2)`  - it will generate the correct fee amount based on the differing constant value in the derived method.

Now I needed to create a `Rental` class and in `main()` create an array of type rental class to hold Rental objects (which consist of a Movie object, renterId and daysLate). 
Here is the method that takes in an array of Rental objects and returns the late fees due on all rentals in the array:

```
/**
 * lateFeesOwed returns the amount of money due for late fees on all movies 
 *  which are located in an array of Rentals.
 *
 *  @return feeDue the amount of money due for late fees.
 */
public static double lateFeesOwed(Rental[] rentalArray){
    double feeDue = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < rentalArray.length; i++)
    {
        feeDue += rentalArray[i].calcFees();  //This is part of the problem??

    }

    return feeDue;
}
```

and this method calls:

```
/**
 * CalcFees returns the amount of money due for late fees on a movie rental.
 *
 *  @return feeDue the amount of money due for late fees.
 */
public double calcFees(){
  double feeDue = rentalName.calcLateFees(this.daysLate);  
  return feeDue;
}
```

But the problem is that the `calcFees()` method is calling `calcLateFees()` but instead of calling the derived class, it is calling the Movie class and returning the incorrect amount.

I'm not sure where my issue is preventing the overridden method `calcLateFees()` from being called.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

> These derived classes have no other variables, just a different FEE_AMT.

This is the problem. Data members are not polymorphic. What you need to do is turn `FEE_AMT` into a method, and override that method in the derived classes.

```
// Movie

public double calcLateFees(int days){
    return(days * getFeeAmt());
}

protected abstract double getFeeAmt(); // or implement if you wish

// Action etc

@Override
protected double getFeeAmt() { return ...; }
```

Comment: +1, i needed to read the whole thing twice and before i know there is already an answer down here .. :P